# PyTest - Apply mock to all tests

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I would like to apply a mock/patch that will apply to all tests, how can I do this?

I had tried putting it in a fixture, and using the fixture everywhere, but, the reapplication of the mock/patch on each test was leading to inconsistent `id(my_mock)` values.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can make a fixture applied only once for all the test suite execution by scoping the fixture to `'session'`, and using it in all your tests:

```
import pytest
from unittest import mock

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def my_thing_mock():
    with mock.patch.object(TheThingYouWantToMock, 'some_attribute') as _fixture:
        yield _fixture
```

Comment: Nice solution! But does this mean we have to use both pytest and unittest?

Comment: @Nicoowr This code doesn't really use unittest except it's mocking library, so I don't think it's really a downside. If you want though you can also use the `monkeypatch` fixture (https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/monkeypatch.html) in pytest to achieve the same results!

Comment: If you want an `autouse` fixture like this to apply to all methods in a test file, it seems to work OK if you put it at the top of the file and just omit the `scope` keyword. The docs don't seem too helpful on these points.

Comment: Which file does this need to go in? Or asked differently: how is made sure that this is executed before any tests run?